# Retrieving product list form openerp 7

Tags: python, odoo

I'm currently working on a mobile app that connects with an openerp 7 instance though XML-RPC.
Although xmlrpc comm between iOS & Openerp 7 works perfectly, I'm puzzled at which objects I need to interact with at the openerp side in order to get the product list with only the items I want and to post a sale.

Any one?

Thanx,
M

Comment: i don't get your part with the sale. could you please explain that part a bit more? thx

Comment: What Im doing is integrate openerp with a mobile POS to process card present transaction. I need to "tell" openerp that the transaction was approved and the sale actually succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working through `XML-RPC` is pretty much like working directly on the server, only slower.

To get the product list you'll need to interact wit `product.product`, and to narrow the list (and the data) you'll need to specify a `domain` such as `domain=[('color','=','red'),('style','=','sport')]` and `fields=['id','name','...']`.

Hopefully that's enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you Ethan. How about "telling" openerp that the sale was made and paid?

Comment: @Martha: using [openerplib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openerp-client-lib) you use `.read(...)` to read the data and `.write(...)` to write data.

Comment: but write isn't enough to get the sale workflow to "flow". or is there a possibility to send workflow signals or to use model methods with xmlrpc?

Comment: @CZoellner: I haven't tested this (as I haven't needed it yet) but I believe you can use XMLRPC to call any method of the OpenERP object.

Comment: then there shouldn't be any problem to get a sale workflow "flowing" :-)